# Adding element after Chartist chart

Tags: javascript, charts, chartist.js

I'm trying to add a paragraph of text underneath a [Chartist](https://gionkunz.github.io/chartist-js/index.html) chart. However, it seems that Chartist defers the actual creation of the DOM element until some unknown future point.

Expectation:

- Create new Chartist chart, then
- Append element to dom after chart
- Chart appears before element in DOM

Actual:

- Chart appears after element in DOM

How do I get my element to occur after the chart? I see an event API but they don't list if there are any "complete" or "added" event.

```js
var data = {
  series: [5, 3, 4]
};

new Chartist.Pie('.thing', data);

$('.thing').append("<p>should appear after/below chart!</p>")
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/chartist/0.9.4/chartist.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/chartist/0.9.4/chartist.js"></script>
<div class="thing"></div>
```

Comment: Instead of trying to solve the problem, work around it. :-) Have a second div to put your text in and leave the .thing div for Chartist to manipulate.

Comment: Not a bad idea- I would probably make a the `div` in javascript instead of putting it in the html.

Answer (score 2):

As @blm suggests, you could add an additional DOM element, but just in case you've got some constraint requiring you to build it this way, you can .append() your paragraph to `.thing` in Chartist's .on('draw') method.

```js
var data = {
  series: [5, 3, 4]
};

var chart = new Chartist.Pie('.thing', data);

chart.on('draw', function(){
    $('.thing').append("<p>should appear after/below chart!</p>")
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/chartist/0.9.4/chartist.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/chartist/0.9.4/chartist.js"></script>
<div class="thing"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I came across this question because I needed if for a project myself.

Problem with @brianrhea's answer is that you will append the p tag for every item in the series array. If you want only to append it a single time use following code

```
var data = {
    series: [5, 3, 4]
};

var chart = new Chartist.Pie('.thing', data);
chart.on('draw', function (data) {
    if (data.index === 0) {
         $('.thing').append("<p>should appear after/below chart!</p>");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a `created` event which seems perfect for this job.

```
var data = {
    series: [5, 3, 4]
};

var chart = new Chartist.Pie('.thing', data);
chart.on('created', function(){
    $(id).append("<p>should appear after/below chart!</p>");
});
```